# R code for plotting using layout() works when executed line by line but not when wrapped up in a function

Tags: r, plot, layout, time-series, xts

I am using `xts` package.

```
library(xts)
```

The following works totally fine:

```
mydata = xts(rnorm(200), order.by = Sys.Date() - 1:200)
layout(matrix(c(1,1,2,3), 2, 2, byrow = TRUE),
         widths=c(1,1), heights=c(1,2))
plot(mydata, main = 'mydata Time Series')
acf(mydata, main = 'mydata acf', lag = 10)
pacf(mydata, main = 'mydata pacf', lag = 10)
```

[image: good]

But when I use the exact same thing as a function the plots are not shown well

```
mydata = xts(rnorm(200), order.by = Sys.Date() - 1:200)

return_plot <- function(mydata, lag = 10){
  layout(matrix(c(1,1,2,3), 2, 2, byrow = TRUE),
         widths=c(1,1), heights=c(1,2))
  plot(mydata, main = 'mydata Time Series')
  acf(mydata, main = 'mydata acf', lag = lag )
  pacf(mydata, main = 'mydata pacf', lag = lag)
}

return_plot(mydata)
```

[image: bad]

Any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `print(plot(mydata, main = 'mydata Time Series'))` in your function.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works. Any idea about why it happens?

Comment: @BIM I think it is because `plot.xts` uses *lattice* or *ggplot2* plotting system, not R base plotting system. I once had a similar experience when trying `ggplot2`. So I tried my luck  to wrap up your `plot` with `print` and it worked.